# Use python to run shell script with Popen behaves differently in python command line and actual program

Tags: python, popen

I have a shell script that I want to call from a python program, but doesn't work at all with following code(Popen already imported):

```
bf_dir = '/home/wireless'
bf_path = os.path.join(bf_dir, 'airdispatch.sh')
sh = Popen("sudo " + bf_path, shell=True)
print sh.communicate()
```

Ideally, the script will generate output files, but by executing above code, those files don't appear, and the "print" result is `[None, None]`. My guess is that the "Popen" somehow doesn't get executed at all, or might be that I made a mistake here. So I run above code in python command line, but it turns out that everything works fine. How can that be possible? Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are not getting any output from the command is because you have not told the subprocess to open pipes for communication...

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

sh = Popen("sudo %s" % bf_path, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

Now communicate will return the output of both stdout and stderr. Also, its possible that the sudo might cause you problems if it requires a password input.

Comment: As far as I can see sudo may work that way - tested it with 'sudo apt-get update' but it is really messy since you have to write the password in plain text.

Answer (score 1):

Using shell=True and invoking sudo sounds risky [(look here)](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments), I'd rather use Popen with a list and not as a text string.

```
sh = Popen(['sudo', bf_path], shell=False, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

Comment: This is false. When you use the shell flag you can pass a string. You should probably delete this before downvotes.

Comment: Sorry didn't see the shell-flag just know I ran into this problem myself a wile back with Popen returning a [None, None] and it resolved itself using the list instead of a space-separated string.

Comment: That may be so, but this answer is still wrong and you should probably delete it. You copy and pasted it with the shell flag right there.

Comment: So I think that should rid it of its erroroneous statement and it should work