# Popen giving error in python when trying to execute a script

Tags: python, debian, popen

Have having issues with Popen in python. Code in question:

```
from subprocess import Popen
Popen(["nohup", "/usr/local/bin/python2.7  /somescript.py"])
```

With following error:

```
 failed to run command `/usr/local/bin/python2.7  /somescript.py': No such file or directory
```

Thing is that when I run the same command in a terminal, it works and the file definitely exists.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778403/use-python-to-run-shell-script-with-popen-behaves-differently-in-python-command?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing 2 `"` and a `,` `Popen` takes a list of arguments.  Try this:

```
from subprocess import Popen
Popen(["nohup", "/usr/local/bin/python2.7",  "/somescript.py"])
```